# JavaScript Increment number every time (if statement) is true

Tags: javascript

In my code I am retrieved data from the data base every 30 seconds using AJAX. I want to use JavaScript to increment variable wht every time data is received from the database (every 30 seconds) and when if statement is true. Below code is working and incrementing to 1 but it doesn't go above 1. Does anyone has a solution for this problem?

```
      <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                   ajax_call = function() {
                   $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "test.php",
                   dataType: "html",           
                   success: function (response) {
                   color = response;
                   console.log(color);
           
               if (color == white){
                    var wht = (function(w) {
                    return function() {
                    w += 1;
                    return w;
                    }
                }(0));
                document.getElementById("memo").value = wht();
           }else{
                console.log("Color is not white");
           }

        var interval = 30000;
        setInterval(ajax_call, interval);

        });
      </script>




       <script>
            const minusButtonFw = document.getElementById('memo-minus');
            const plusButtonFw = document.getElementById('memo-plus');
            var memo = document.getElementById('memo');

            minusButtonFw.addEventListener('click', event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const currentValue = Number(memo.value);
            memo.value = currentValue - 1;
         });

            plusButtonFw.addEventListener('click', event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const currentValue = Number(memo.value);
            memo.value = currentValue + 1;
         });
       </script>
```

Comment: are you looking for `setInterval`?

Comment: you have to give more information.

Comment: @Naren I want to increment variable wht every time if statement is true.

Comment: you keep passing 0 to `wht` function. I think maybe you meant to pass `document.getElementById("memo").value` ?

Comment: @CrayonViolent you are absolutely right. I don't know how to write my function to make it add to the last number that has been incremented.

Comment: More efficient ways of coding, but working off code you currently have.. something like `var memoElem = document.getElementById("memo"); var wht = (function(w) {..}(+memoElem.value)); memoElem.value = wht();`

Comment: Well 'w' is a function parameter. Its scope is limited to the function, so next time the function is called, 'w' has the same old value.

Comment: @CrayonViolent I used document.getElementById("memo").value  = wht(); to display my incremented number in html.

Comment: Where is the Ajax call? WHere is the interval?

Comment: @epascarello I just added that to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your variable `wht` is a function. If you simply want to keep track of the number of time the if conditions is true you can do it by making the variable static (literaly). you can achive this by storing the variable in a global scope.

Also there are sytax errors in your code too where wht is defined.

try this

```
$(function () {
    var memo = document.getElementById("memo");
    memo.val = 0;
    var ajax_call = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "test.php",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response) {
                color = response;
                console.log(color);
                if (color == white) {
                    memo.val++;
                    memo.value = memo.val;
                } else {
                    console.log("Color is not white");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    var interval = 30000;
    setInterval(ajax_call, interval);
});
```

**A Note:**
If the response is managed by you, I would recomend sending the response as json rather than simply sending it as an html with just one value color.

Comment: Thank you brother, your code worked very well. jazakallah.

Comment: @CoderJay NM & Ameen. Don’t forget to set the answer :).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to keep track of "w".  Your current setup is using "w" as a parameter to a function.  You'd need to keep it outside of the function and increment it from inside the function.  You'll also need to wrap that function in an interval  Something like the following:

```
var w = 0;

function setWhite(color) {
    if (color == white) {
        w++;
        document.getElementById("memo").value = w;
    } else {
        console.log("Color is not white");
    }
}

setInterval(function() {
    setWhite(color);
}, 30000);
```

This should give you what you want.  I didn't run the code so there are probably syntactical errors that you'll need to correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try change the line

```
document.getElementById("memo").value = wht();
```

to

```
document.getElementById("memo").value = wht(document.getElementById("memo").value);
```

Your full code:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                   ajax_call = function() {
                   $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "test.php",
                   dataType: "html",           
                   success: function (response) {
                   color = response;
                   console.log(color);
           
               if (color == white){
                    var wht = (function(w) {
                    return function() {
                    w += 1;
                    return w;
                    }
                }(0));
                document.getElementById("memo").value = wht(document.getElementById("memo").value);
           }else{
                console.log("Color is not white");
           }

        var interval = 30000;
        setInterval(ajax_call, interval);

        });
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an example with `setInterval`. I made `w` global so it will work. Try this:

```js
var w = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (color == white) {
        w++;
        document.getElementById("memo").value = w;
    } else {
        console.log("Color is not white");
    }
}, 30000);
```

Comment: My bad.  i must've taken too long to submit my answer that you already answered it.  Now there's a dupe.  Can I delete it mine?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will your code work if I don't use setInterval part of it? because I already used setInterval for my AJAX .

Comment: @CoderJay, If there is already an interval, just include the function in the interval and make `w` a global variable.

Comment: @myjobistobehappy I will, Thanks.